# UIDatePickerについて

Tags: swift, ios

ViewContoroller1でセットしたUIDatePickerの日付を
ViewContoroller2のラベルに表示させるにはどのような手続きが必要なのでしょうか？

Comment: 現状の質問ではSoAさんが何処まで理解されているかが分かりません。今実装されているViewControllerのクラスを記載することは出来ますか？

Comment: 完全にViewが分かれて遷移してしまうのであれば`AppDelegate`に逃がすなど、別にTabViewやSplitViewなどで親Viewがあるのであればそのまま参照できるかと思いますが、どう言った構成になっているのでしょうか？